# JavaMailSenderImpl configuring with one email address and using another as MimeMessageHelper.setFrom but says permission issue

Tags: java, spring, email

I have configured my email properties but while sending email from address is changing dynamically

I have tried with the same email address as from address then it's working but if i use different one getting permission issue.

email configuration is:

```
<bean id = "mailSender"class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl"><
    property name = "host"value="mail.******.com"/><
    property name="port"value="587"/><
    property name="username"value="support@*****.com"/><
    property name="password"value="******"/><
    property name="javaMailProperties">
        <props><
    prop key="mail.transport.protocol">smtp</prop><
    prop key="mail.debug">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

```
public void sendBulkEmail(String[] to, NewCampaignDTO campaign, String mailTemplate) throws MailException {
    if (isMailsBlocaked()) {
        to = new String[0];
    }
    MimeMessagePreparator preparator = imsGeneralUtils.prepareBulkEmailMessage(to, campaign, mailTemplate);
    // Send Message
    javaMailSender.send(preparator);

}
public MimeMessagePreparator prepareBulkEmailMessage(String[] to, Object campaign, String mailTemplate) {
    return new MimeMessagePreparator() {
        @Override
        public void prepare(MimeMessage mimeMessage) throws Exception {
            MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true, CharEncoding.UTF_8);
            message.setBcc(AddToStringArray(to, DEFAULT_MAIL_TO_ALL));
            message.setSubject(campaign.getSubject());
            message.setFrom(campaign.getFromEmail(), campaign.getFromName());
            message.setReplyTo(campaign.getReplyToEmail());
            Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<>();
            model.put("objInfo", campaign.getEmailBody());
            model.put("url", getSettingValue(Settings.FRONT_END_APP_URL));
            String body = FreeMarkerTemplateUtils
                    .processTemplateIntoString(freeMakerConfig.getTemplate(mailTemplate), model);
            message.setText(body, true);
        }
    };
}
```

Failed messages: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 550 5.7.1 Client does not have permissions to send as this sender

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable SMTP for that email.If problem persists then enable debug and see.
Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

SMTP is already enabled for both the emails. The exact problem is I have two emails ids which are support@***.com and info@***.com
I'm using support@***.com for authentication and info@***.com using to send email then getting the permissino issue.
If I use same email  id for authenticate and send email it's working fine and when use from address different as login user then facing the issue.